# How to get the diff from two arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Hello i have this arrays

```
"restaurant_beers": [
      {
        "beer_id": "3"
      },
      {
        "beer_id": "2"
      },
      {
        "beer_id": "1"
      },
      {
        "beer_id": "18"
      },
      {
        "beer_id": "19"
      },
      {
        "beer_id": "23"
      },
      {
        "beer_id": "24"
      }
    ],
    "merged_beers": [
      {
        "beer_id": "2"
      },
      {
        "beer_id": "3"
      },
      {
        "beer_id": "1"
      },
      {
        "beer_id": "23"
      }
    ]
```

after making very much test with `array_diff`,it returns the `merged_beers` array, any suggestion?

but im trying to get only the `beer_id` 18, 19, 24

is there any other way to do this? or maybe with a for?

thanks

Comment: Show us how you use `array_diff`.

Comment: @GrumpysaysReinstateMonica `        return array_keys(array_diff_key($array2,$array1));
`

Comment: sometimes is not returning nothing...

Comment: Please [update your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59829895/edit). Include what `$array2` and `$array1` looks like.

Comment: It would be easier if your arrays were more `"restaurant_beers": [3,2,1,18,19...]`

Comment: @GrumpysaysReinstateMonica array1 and array2 are in the question, first `restaurant_beers` is the first array and the other is array2

Comment: @NigelRen should be fine?

Comment: @NigelRen i can modify it

Comment: @DanteCervantes How are you using `$array2` in `array_diff()` if `$array2` is _returned by_ `array_diff()`?

Comment: @GrumpysaysReinstateMonica 

`restaurant_beers` = $array1
`merged_beers` = $array2
$results = array_diff($array2, $array1);

Comment: `array_diff` is not generally useful for multi-dimensional arrays.

Comment: @Barmar what is useful?

Comment: In your case you can use `array_column()` to get a simple array of beer IDs, then use `array_diff` to compare those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`array_diff` expects a flat array, not a multidimensional array.

Use `array_column()` to extract the beer IDs from each array.

```
$diff = array_diff(array_column($array['restaurant_beers'], 'beer_id'),
                   array_column($array['merged_beers'], 'beer_id'));
```

This will return an array like

```
['18', '19', '24']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, is exactly what i was looking for